# Twilio flex call task type

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm creating a call task using twilio task router using cloud function. I am successfully able to create task and it's showing up in twilio flex as a task, but it's a default task when i accept it automatically finish to complete screen shows up. I'm trying to create a call task that shows up like a call. Where agent accept it and make a call to customer, but didn't get it as call task.

Below is the node js code that i'm using it in cloud function.

```
const task = await client.taskrouter.workspaces('WS******************')
                                               .tasks
                                               .create({attributes: JSON.stringify({
                                                "type": "call",
                                                    "contact": snap.data().phoneNumber,
                                                    "customer-value": "gold",
                                                    "task-reason": "support",
                                                 "name": snap.data().phoneNumber,
                                                 "identity":snap.data().phoneNumber
                                                 }) ,workflowSid:'WW*********************'});
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds as though you are trying to create an outbound call from Flex. I recommend you read through this blog post to see the options for [placing outbound calls in Flex](https://www.twilio.com/blog/flex-programmable-dialpad-outbound-calling).